# There will always be adjacent slices summing to 9 on pentagon

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Consider a circle divided into $5$ parts radially.

Suppose we have $21$ beads that we place, distributing however we like among the $5$ regions.

The claim is that there is always a pair of adjacent sectors whose union has $9$ or more beads.

### My work

I took an experimental approach to this:

I begin by simplifying the problem greatly if we consider a circle split into $3$ parts with $3$ beads, then there is always a pair of adjacent sectors that sum to $2$ (this can be checked by casework)

If we increase the bead count to $4$ beads, then case work again can verify that there is always a pair of adjacent sectors that sum to $3$.

If we increase to $5$ beads, it seems that we can always form adjacent sectors that sum to $4$. This hints at a proof by induction that given $3$ sectors, and $K$ beads its always possible to find a pair of adjacent sectors that sum to $\left\lceil \dfrac{2}{3} K \right\rceil$ (consider the case where we take the largest multiple of $3$ less than $K$, split evenly by it (clearly $\dfrac{2}{3}K$ is possible here) Then distribute the remainder beads, giving $+1$ either way if we attempt to minimize the sum of pairs of adjacent sides)

Now we consider splitting into $4$ parts instead of $5$, but I realized if I continue this analysis this way it was getting messy, and certainly not a $30$ second aha! that one would expect from the math GRE subject test.

Is there some way to use pigeonhole to do this quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Label the regions as $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5$ in order of appearance. We then have the constraints:

$A_1 + A_2 \le 8$

$A_2 + A_3 \le 8$

$A_3 + A_4  \le 8$

$A_4 + A_5  \le 8$

$A_5 + A_1 \le 8$

Adding these up, we get that $2 \times (A_1 + A_2 + A_3 + A_4 + A_5)  \le40$, but we know that the sum of the number of beads in all the regions is $21$, and $2$ times that is $42$, which allows us to see that it's not possible.

Comment: That's a perfectly correct solution (upvoted) but it's not clear to me how it is related to pigeon holes.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1,\dots,x_5$ be the number of beads in each sector. If there are at most $8$ beads in any two adjacent sectors, then $\sum_i (x_i+x_{i+1 \bmod 5})\leq 40$ and so $\sum_i x_i \leq 20$.

Answer (score 1):

This goes along the lines of [the solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2682935/152299) by @Green, but with an  explicit use of pigeonhole principle.

Let $A_1$ through $A_5$ denote number of beads in five sectors.
Let in turn $B_i=A_i+A_{i+1}$ (with $B_5=A_5+A_1$of course) denote sums considered.

Then $\sum_iB_i = 2\cdot\sum_iA_i = a\cdot 21=42$

Now we have $42$ beads distributed among five $B$ pigeonholes.
Of course not all such distributions are possible. Every bead in any $A_i$ hole counts into two $B$ holes, namely to $B_i$ and to $B_{i-1}$ (with $B_0$ being the same as $B_5$), so, for example, we can't have $B_3=10$ with $B_2=B_4=0$. Anyway *each* possible distribution of $21$ beads over $A_1,\dots A_5$ generates one of possible distributions of $42$ among $B_1,\dots B_5$.

And from the generalized pigeonhole principle, if we distribute $N=42$ beads over $k=5$ holes, then there is at least one hole containing at least
$$\left\lceil\frac Nk\right\rceil = \left\lceil\frac {42}5\right\rceil = \left\lceil 8.4\right\rceil = 9$$
beads. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pigeonhole works super quickly:  how can you maximize the number of beads to not get 9 beads in adjacent regions?  By putting $4$ in each ... (putting more than $4$ in one region and having $8$ maximum for adjacent doesn't even get you to $20$ when going around)

Comment: The problem with trying to do it constructively is we can also have runs of more than 4, much less than needed, much less than needed, more than 4. And it’s not clear how to efficiently argue against all these different strategies

Comment: Well, not to me; maybe if you add more data I can see how a rigorous argument easily pops out

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Yes, you're quite right; it's not that simple as I made it out to be!